# How to customise names of the JS files produced by Vue CLI?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-4

I can't find documentation on how to minimize assets and produce *.min.js files using vue cli.
Im using vue cli version 4.2.3.

I require the extention to be *.min.js for rollbar to function correctly.

How would you go about configuring vue cli to produce minimized assets? (no TS involved).

Comment: I'm pretty sure VueCLI minify the js files in `production` mode. So I guess your problem is just the naming, right?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm sure Vue CLI minifies JS output when running `build` in production mode. It's just using different naming convention (no "min.js")

To tweak file names of JS chunks produced by Vue CLI, you can do the following:

Check the default Webpack config Vue CLI uses by running `vue inspect` on command line (dev mode) or `vue inspect --mode production` (production mode)

Look for an `output` (should be near the beginning of the output). In my project it looks like this:

Dev mode:

```js
output: {
    path: '.....some dir\\dist',
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    publicPath: '/',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js'
  },
```

Production mode:

```js
output: {
    path: '.....some dir\\dist',
    filename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
    publicPath: '/',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
  },
```

Now you can tweak it - add [vue.config.js](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) to your project if you don't have it already and add following:

```js
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: config => {
      if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
        config.output.filename = 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].min.js'
        config.output.chunkFilename = 'js/[name].[contenthash:8].min.js'
      } else {
        config.output.filename = 'js/[name].js'
        config.output.chunkFilename = 'js/[name].js';
      }
    }
}
```

`[name]` and `[contenthash:8]` are Webpack placeholders - more info in [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputfilename)

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed.